# How to ask a question and define what I mean?

Tags: technical-writing, editing, formatting, structure, phrasing

I am in the middle of the painful process of buying a car. I am trying to do much of my legwork online before going into a dealership. One of the things I hate the most about purchasing a car is settling on a final price. Typically when I do this I like to establish an *out the door* price before going to a dealership. My current phrasing for doing this is:

> The price listed online is $34,800 and I am interested in purchasing the
>   car. Would you take $30,000 out the door: meaning tax, title, and
>   document fees?

Adding the definition of what I mean by *out the door* always feels awkward. Is there a better way to phrase the above such that I can convey my meaning and ask the question?

Comment: For those of you voting to close, this question would have been off topic under the old "what to write" rule. But that rule is changing (see https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/getting-writers-out-of-its-rut) and this is a "how do I express this idea" question which is now on topic for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... How about?

> "Would you take $30,000 total, including tax, title, and document
>   fees?"

Wonder how you ended up asking this question at this --Writers-- site?
Is there a need for a StackExchange Bartering site?  :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a regional thing, but in Australia, what you are talking about is called the Drive Away price, and dealerships often advertise as such.

This includes all relevant taxes, registration and insurances on the vehicle. Literally everything you need to drive it, legally, out of the yard.